# iTextSharp is rotating the page after the one I want to landscape

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, landscape-portrait

I've cobbled together this code from a few suggestions. It almost works, but it is rotating the page after the one that needs to be. The first page in my example is landscape, but the second is the one that get's rotated. I don't understand what is going on.

```
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
        int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
        {
            document.NewPage();
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

            Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
            document.SetPageSize(psize.Width > psize.Height ? PageSize.A4.Rotate() : PageSize.A4);

            switch (psize.Rotation)
            {
                case 0:
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 90:
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, psize.Height);
                    break;
                case 180:
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, -1f, 0, 0, -1f, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 270:
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 1.0F, -1.0F, 0, psize.Width, 0);
                    break;
            }                
        }
        document.Close();
        writer.Close();
```

You guys see it?

Comment: Different pages in a PDF can have different sizes. Thus,  the `Document` attribute `PageSize` you set does not change the size of the current page but that of new pages created later. What is your actual user case? You appear to merely want to copy some pages. That should be done using `PdfCopy`. That class correctly organizes page sizes for you.

Comment: You're right. PdfCopy does seem to be working well for me. Thank you. I will answer my own question I guess. I'm unsure what the best procedure is.

Comment: Answering yourself is ok, in particular as I merely gave a hint. If the answer were a mere copy of someone else's comment, though, one should ask that person to write the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using PdfCopy as suggested by [mkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl). It seems to be working so far and is much simpler. Here is what I'm using.

```
        using (Document document = new Document())
        {
            using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                document.Open();
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                for (int page = 0; page < reader.NumberOfPages;)
                {
                    ++page;
                    copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, page));
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having a case where pdf documents coming in through our filing system were occasionally given a rotation property by the client's scanner. This was causing an issue with another system where they're sent. I used Erosebe's code with mkl's fix to create a class to do this correctly if anyone needs it in the future.

The output will be a correctly oriented document with a 0 rotation. It uses itextsharp.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text;

public static void UnRotate(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    using (Document document = new Document())
    {
        using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            using(PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputPath))
            {
                document.Open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

                int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle psize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(i);
                    document.SetPageSize(psize.Width > psize.Height ? PageSize.LETTER.Rotate() : PageSize.LETTER);

                    document.NewPage();
                    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                    switch (psize.Rotation)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1f, 0, 0);
                            break;

                        case 90:
                            writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, -1f, 1f, 0, 0, psize.Height);
                            break;

                        case 180:
                            writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, -1f, 0, 0, -1f, psize.Width, psize.Height);
                            break;

                        case 270:
                            writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(page, 0, 1f, -1f, 0, psize.Width, 0);
                            break;

                        default:
                            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Unexpected page rotation: [{0}].", psize.Rotation));
                    }
                }
                document.Close();
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```